# How to make a weblink clickable when comments are made

Tags: php

I need your help with making a weblink clickable when comments are made on mf website.. The code I have below does not achieve that. It only inserts (Code Not Shown), and the website is not clickable.

Thank you for your help.

```
      $reg = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps|www)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/g";

  if(preg_match($reg, $comment, $url,))         
       { 

  $comment_body = preg_replace($reg, "<a href = " .$url[0]. "> $url[0] </a> ", $comment);

                  }
```

Comment: This is quite risky you know, it could lead to your comments becoming a spam magnet, or even open you up to XSS attacks. You do have some kind of way of checking the URL before turning it into a hyperlink, right?

Comment: @gordonm what if i apply htmlspecialchars() ? Will that reduce/remove spamming ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is how you specify your href: html likes quotes around sstuff like that. try:

```
$comment_body = preg_replace($reg, "<a href = \"" .$url[0]. "\"> $url[0] </a> ", $comment);
```

otherwise it will look like:

```
href=some_url.whatever
```

instead of

```
href="some_url.whatever"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url    = 'this is an url http://www.test.com';
$result = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $url);

echo $result;
```